# Changing the colon to a comma after the vol.(num.) in bst file

Tags: punctuation, natbib

I need to change the format in the `.bst` file that I am using. The format currently as:

> Beth, T. and Gollmann, D. (1989). Algorithm Engineering for Public Key
>   Algorithm. IEEE Journal on selected areas in communications 7 (4):
>   458–465.

I want them to be as:

> Beth, T. and Gollmann, D. (1989). Algorithm Engineering for Public Key
>   Algorithm. IEEE Journal on selected areas in communications, 7 (4),
>   458–465.

I need to add comma after the Journal's name and also changing the colon after the series number into comma.

What commands should I add and on which function should I make changes?

Is the following function the right one to add changes on?

```
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { series empty$
       { "" }
       { series emphasize }
     if$
     swap$ bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.connect output
    }
  if$
}
```

I have also other functions in bst file where I think they might be related, such as:

```
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
```

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: if you are using `natbib` you might consider using `custom-bib` to set up your own .bst file - basically you run `latex makebst.tex` and follow the instructions - much easier than messing around with a .bst file

Comment: Which style exactly you use? It is not that difficult to tweak the file once you tell us which one is it.

Comment: @prettygully: the advice to consider running the `makebst` program through LaTeX is sound. Just a quick note: It's not necessary to be using `natbib` in order to benefit from the capabilities of the `makebst` utility.

Comment: Please, tell what bibliography style you're loading, so that we can experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention *which* bibliography style file you're using, so I'll assume that it's either that's provided by the `natbib` package (such as `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, etc) or was generated by the `makebst` utility (which was written by the author of the `natbib` package.

In your `.bst` file, you need to locate the function `format.vol.num.pages`; it looks like this in the file `plainnat.bst` file:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "\penalty0 (" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ":\penalty0 " * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Note the colon (`:`), which happens to be in the fifth line from the bottom in this version of the `format.vol.num.pages` function. (Depending on the `.bst` file you use, it may be in a different location within the `format.vol.num.pages` function.) Change the colon to a comma and save the file under a new name, e.g., `plainnat-mara.bst`. You could save the new file either to your current working directory or some other directory where your TeX distribution tends to look for BibTeX style files. Be sure to refer to the new style file from now on.

Comment: Thank you Mico for drawing my attention to the ratings thing, I never looked at that, I so involved with the answers which is the thing that made me not looking at anything else, I will keep that in mind in the future. As for my question, I am sorry I didn't mention that, yes, I am using natbib. What you said in they reply was a great help. Thank you. And, I will mark it as a useful answer! Now I will try to find where to add comma (,) after the journal's name.

Comment: @Mara: You're welcome. A separate issue, related to inserting a comma after the journal name: *Which* bibliography style file (`.bst`) do you use? Is it a more or less standard `.bst` file that can be found on the CTAN (Comprehensive TeX Archive Network), such as `plainnat.bst`, or is it a custom-written `.bst` file? If it's the former, you may want to post a new question related to comma-after-journal-name issue.

Comment: As for the bibliography I am using, I think, the original material was called chicago style, but this wasn't its name when I got it, because there were modifications had been already done on it. Regarding my question: That's good I didn't need to post a new question because I have just solved the problem. The comma now is after the journal's name. Again, great thanks to you Mico, you have inspired me!